# Exchange Server: create a separate database for each mailbox?

Tags: database, exchange-server, mailboxer, edb

I have read a number of articles that seem to suggest that Exchange Server 2013 can be configured with a separate database (EDB file) per mailbox, but I can't find an article that says how to do that.

Is that possible, and if so, how do I accomplish that?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *.EDB file is a file which store all mailboxes created inside them (a kind of Database file). Technically you could create multiple *.EDB files and then put only one mailbox in that. However this wouldn´t really make sense so I couldn´t see why somebody would mention that in some articles that this is a good idea.

Additional: The amount of possible *.EDBs is limited so doing that do not make any sense. An Exchange Standard Server allow 5 *.EDBs and Enterprise Server 100 (see [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ilvancri/2010/04/22/exchange-2010-standard-edition-limited-to-5-databases/)).

The correct way however is to use multiple *.EDBs and then spread the workload caused by the mailboxes across them. This is known to be best practices as the preferred DB size is 200GB for a stand alone server and 2TB for a High availability setup as mentioned [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee832792(v=exchg.150).aspx) for Exchange 2013.

*P.S. You also can setup a quota for 5GB on one *.EDB and all mailboxes inside that one would use the quota. On another *.EDB you can specify only 1 GB. This allows you to handle the quota on the DB level and not on the mailbox level.*

Comment: could happen :)